# Installing Hue without CDH in a no internet access environment

Tags: cloudera, hue

I am trying to update the Hue on hdp on no internet access environment.
However, the compiling progress needs to download some python package from the internet.
Also, I cannot find any pre-built hue package without cdh(I am working on hdp, so install cdh just for hue is inconvenient).

Does anyone have a good idea for it?

Answer (score 0):

It needs more than just Python packages, there are external build dependencies as well as Cloudera and Maven Central packages that it downloads.

Download Hue where you do have internet. Build a tarball using `make clean prod`, then copy it to the cluster.

It runs in a virtualenv, so as long as built with a matching OS & Python version, should be fine.

I've done this since Hue 3.11 on an HDP cluster.